# Hyphen at beginning of regex causes it to stop matching (python 2.7) - but at the end it's fine?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm writing a simple script to dump the tracks, artists, and times of a bandcamp album (https://nihonkizuna.bandcamp.com/album/nihon-kizuna), but I'm having trouble with the regex. For context, the track titles are in the format "Artist - Title". I'm trying to separate the dumped track titles so that I have the artist in one list and the title in another, then writing these and the time to a csv.

For some reason, the expression:

```
(.*) -
```

Finds the artist correctly, but:

```
- (.*)
```

Fails to find the title correctly. Instead I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I've tried escaping the hyphen, but python returns "None" for a match as long as it's the first character. I've tried testing it by regexing an actual title, "- 9 Samurai", and it still fails.

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import html
import re
import requests

page = requests.get("https://nihonkizuna.bandcamp.com/album/nihon-kizuna")
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

tracks = tree.xpath('//table[@id ="track_table"]//td[@class="title-col"]/div[@class="title"]/a/span/text()')
time = tree.xpath('//table[@id ="track_table"]//td[@class="title-col"]/div[@class="title"]/span/text()')
newtimes = []
artists = []
newtracks = []

for item in time:
    newitem = item.strip()
    newtimes.append(newitem)

for item in tracks:
    track_item = re.match("(.*) -", item)
    artists.append(track_item.group(1))
    newitem2 = re.match("- (.*)", item)
    newtracks.append(newitem2.group(1))

raw_data = {"track": newtracks, "artist": artists, "time": newtimes}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ["track", "artist", "time"])
df.index += 1

df.to_csv(raw_input("Input the csv path."))
```

Comment: What exactly is the value you're trying to match…?!

Comment: `re.match` only matches *at the start of the input string*. Use `re.search()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation to [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) states:

> If zero or more characters **at the beginning** of string match the regular expression pattern, (...).

Use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead.

Comment: Of course it would be something that simple. Take this as a lesson to re-read the documentation every so often, unlike me!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use a regular [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
artists, newtracks = zip(*[item.split(" - ") for item in tracks])
```

The `zip(*[...])` here would *unzip* the list of 2-item tuples into two separate sequences allowing us to separate artists and newtracks.

---

Note that both solutions are vulnerable *in case a dash can be a part of artist or track name*. On this particular page, artist and track names are always met "together", joined with `-`. If you are worried about cases like these and you can sacrifice performance in exchange for quality and robustness - *follow the track pages* where you have artists and songs defined separately. If you do that, make sure to have a web-scraping `requests` session defined while you crawl the website.

Comment: @RedX yeah, thinking about that at the moment and exploring the input data for such cases, thanks.

Comment: @RedX on this particular page, there are no cases when an artist name has `-` (with spaces) inside. Note that song names might have that as well and the regex solution is also vulnerable to this hypothetical problem.